# Why do helicopters experience a brief dip in altitude during IGE marginal power takeoffs?

Tags: aerodynamics, helicopter, takeoff, ground-effect, rotary-wing

The scenario is this: A helicopter is hovering IGE, and executes a marginal power takeoff. What causes the dip in altitude that occurs around 10 knots during the takeoff?

Most pilots seem to describe this event as, "feeling as though the aircraft is leaving a cushion of air." Is it caused by the increase in induced flow through the rotor system, thereby briefly reducing blade alpha until reaching ETL? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a discussion of this phenomenon in Raymond Prouty's book Helicopter Performance, Stability and Control. Chapter 3 describes momentum methods for the physics in forward flight, including the transition from hover to forward flight in ground effect.

[image]

Above image is from the book, and illustrates what happens:

> Test experience, however, shows that during transition from hover to forward flight at heights less than about half the rotor diameter, the (required) power may actually increase rather than decrease. Pilots speak of this as "running off the ground cushion."

> The reversal of ground effect is due to the helicopter overrunning the ground vortex, as illustrated in Figure 3.12...As the leading edge of rotor approaches the ground vortex, the inflow is increased just as if part of the rotor were in a climb, thus increasing the power required. The recovery to a more normal inflow pattern occurs suddenly as the vortex passes under the rotor.

The book cites research conducted in the quoted text, which I have left out. In the figure the described effect happens starting at 15 knots, a function of helicopter disk loading, relative Height Above Terrain etc.

Comment: What an excellent answer! Thank you for taking the time to write it! And I'll have to check out Mr. Prouty's book!